# Настройка Telegram bot + Instant View Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

**1.** **Настроил telegram bot.** Через сайт по cron отправляет в ***приватный*** telegram канал, методами sendPhoto и sendMessage.

так отправляет

$GetContent = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX/sendPhoto?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=XXXXXXX&photo=' . $SRC . '&caption=' . $Content2Send;

и так отправляет

$GetContent = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:XXXXX/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=XXXX&text=' . $content;

**2.** **Настроил Instant View Telegram** на их сайте https://instantview.telegram.org
Перехожу по ссылке из сайта instantview https://t.me/iv?url=https%3A%2F%2Fuka.mvs.gov.ua%2Ftelegram%2F2be6fb8af11ec0cfe1cf8aafe520b66076
77deb8&rhash=ed0b1d82d58212

Все красиво работает. Отображается кнопка "INSTANT VIEW".

**Вопрос:** **Как мне отправлять ботом в телеграм канал ссылку на сайт, чтобы работал INSTANT VIEW?** Пробывал разными методами sendMessage и sendPhoto. Отображается просто ссылка.

Answer (score -2):

есть такая команда 
https://api.telegram.org/bot(TOKEN без скобок)/sendMessage?chat_id=(ID группы без скобок)&text=твое сообщение

Если тебе потребуется отправлять это постоянно в определенное время, пишешь php скрипт и запускаешь его через cron

PHP:

```
$access_token = 'TOKEN_BOT';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
$chat_id = 'id группы'

sendMessage($chat_id, "Твое сообщение");

function sendMessage($chat_id, $message) {
    file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
}
```

Comment: 1.Вы пробывали? Точно работает INSTANT VIEW?

Comment: 2.В каком формате отправлять https:/имясайта/article/xxx или  https://t.me/iv?url=https://имясайта/...

Comment: 3. Если ли в фомате t.me то нужно ли добавлять &rhash=ed0b1d82d58212 ?

Comment: как обычно запускаете php файл на своем сайте https:/имясайта/имя.php

Comment: вот насчет INSTANT VIEW на 100% не уверен что так нужно, так у меня рассылка работает сообщение, твое где то рядышком должно быть